# How to compile dcmtk Android for x86

Tags: android, dcmtk

I followed the dcmtk wiki:http://support.dcmtk.org/redmine/projects/dcmtk/wiki/Howto_CompileAndroid
But it only support arm,the ANDROID_ABI list is only arm's.Is there any way to support X86 cross-compilation?

Comment: I would also like the answer to this

Comment: You may submit a pull request on [DCMTK project](https://github.com/DCMTK/dcmtk/pulls)